# How do we deal with the --continuation-token when using the az devops security group list cmdlet?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-cli, azure-devops-rest-api

How do you work with the `--continuation-token` argument in order to deal with pagination on the command line?

For example if you run:

```
   az devops security group list --org $Organization --project $project > tmp1.json
```

the output is:

```
"continuationToken": "eyJTY29wZUlkIjoiNDQzYzBhYjEtZjY3OC00ZmZkLWE1NTEtNWUzYTU5ZTg0NjEwIiwiUGFnZVNpemUiOjUwMCwiSW5jbHVkZUdyb3VwcyI6dHJ1ZSwiSW5jbHVkZU5vbkdyb3VwcyI6ZmFsc2UsIlBhZ2VuYXRpb25Ub2tlbiI6ImY1MjI5NWI1LWVjNzgtNGNjZS04ODQ4LWFiYzM3ODc5ZmEzZSJ9",
  "graphGroups": [
    {and the rest of the file with the groups listed
```

How do we deal with the ContinuationToken when it is returned?

When

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without dropping back to the API as suggested above.

```
do {
                
        if ($null -eq $token) {
            $groups = az devops security group list --org $Organization --project $project | ConvertFrom-Json
        }
        else {
            $groups = az devops security group list --org $Organization --project $project --continuation-token $Token | ConvertFrom-Json
        }
    
        if ($groups.Length -le 0) { Break; }
        
        $token = $groups[$groups.Count - 1].ContinuationToken
        
        foreach ($group in $groups) {
            # Do stuff and things
            
        }
    }
    while ($null -ne $token)
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do we deal with the --continuation-token when using the az devops security group list cmdlet?

You could re-run the command with the parameters `--continuation-token`:

```
az devops security group list --continuation-token xxxxx --org $Organization --project $project > tmp1.json
```

It will return the next set of results.

For the details, please refer to the document [az devops security group list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/devops/security/group?view=azure-cli-latest#az-devops-security-group-list)：

```
az devops security group list [--continuation-token]
                              [--detect {false, true}]
                              [--org]
                              [--project]
                              [--scope {organization, project}]
                              [--subject-types]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! 

How do you check if the return includes a token?
And then pass that to a second call of the command?

Comment: @Joseph, Do you mean get it automatically?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. I am asking how to properly parse the JSON response and then call the command again to get the next set of results.

Comment: @Joseph, Sorry for the late reply, I lost the reminder until I reviewed my previous reply. To get the continuationtoken, you could get it from the REST API with powershell, like in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73156183/azure-devops-services-rest-api-6-0-deployments-release-list-not-returning-cou