# Azure DevOps Services REST API 6.0: Deployments/Release - List not returning count more than 100

Tags: api, rest, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

Azure DevOps Services REST API 6.0: Deployments/Release - List not returning count more than 100

I'm using doc (Build, Release & Deployment List)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/deployments/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP

Below API call is giving me list of total builds (approx 930)
`GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?$top=999&api-version=6.0`

Whereas it wont show more than 100 releases/deployments with below queries

`GET https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/releases?$top=999&api-version=6.0`
`GET https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/deployments?$top=999&api-version=6.0`

please suggest further if you have any solutions.

Comment: How are you actually invoking the REST API? I frequently see people encounter this type of issue in PowerShell, and there's an easy solution.

Comment: How are you actually invoking the REST API? >> I was testing online https://reqbin.com/

Answer (score 0):

Please try this PowerShell script:

```
[string]$orgurl = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}"
[string]$project = "ProjectName"
[string]$user = ""
[string]$token = "PAT"

[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = "tls12"

# Ignore the error
$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue' 

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))
cls
$headers = @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
$continuationToken = ''
$deployments = @()
Do {
    $uri = "$orgurl/$project/_apis/release/deployments?api-version=6.0&continuationToken=$ContinuationToken"
    $result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Headers $headers
    $deployments += ($result.Content | ConvertFrom-Json).Value
    $continuationToken = $result.Headers.'x-ms-continuationtoken'
    Write-Host "continuationToken:" $continuationToken 
}
While($continuationToken)
$deployments.Count
$deployments.release | Select id, name, url
```

Comment: ```continuationToken: 
1```
output shows as above (i've replaced {organization}, ProjectName, PAT & added username too)
please suggest if i missed anything ?
 i tried adding below commands at the end but result is still missing
```Write-Output "count:" $deployments.Count
Write-Output "release:" $deployments.release | Select id, name, url```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by the first time not passing the `ContinuationToken` parameter the first call.

```
$uri = "$orgurl/$project/_apis/release/deployments?api-version=6.0"
Do {
    $result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Headers $headers
    $uri = "$orgurl/$project/_apis/release/deployments?api-version=6.0&continuationToken=$ContinuationToken"
    $deployments += ($result.Content | ConvertFrom-Json).Value
    $continuationToken = $result.Headers.'x-ms-continuationtoken'
}
```